# Finding row where a column value change in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `DataFrame` that contains cumulative data. One of the columns identifies a new data set. Is there any good way to identify where the column changes value and store the previous row in a new `DataFrame`?

Data example:

```
step_ID   value1    value2  test_step
31        1         2        2
31        2         3        2
31        3         5        2
35        1         5        2  
35        2         8        2
```

I would like to save the values from the last row where `step_id = 31`. I don't always know how many steps are between the values as this `DataFrame` is already sorted by `test_step`.

Comment: How about `df[ (df.step_ID != df.step_ID.shift(-1))].copy()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to split your `DataFrame` according to the `step_ID`, you can use the `groupby` method:

```
df_list = [x for _, x in df.groupby("step_ID")]
```

The variable `df_list` will store a list with the generated data frames. Each data frame will be associated with a `step_ID` value.

Now, to save only the last row, you can iterate through `df_list` and keep only the last row of each `DataFrame`:

```
last_rows = [d.iloc[-1] for d in df_list]
```

The variable `last_rows` will store a list of `Series` objects, each of which represents the last row of a `DataFrame` in `df_list`.

---

**Edit:**

A cleaner way to save only the last rows is to use the method pointed out by @Rick M:

```
df[(df.step_ID != df.step_ID.shift(-1))].copy()
```